# How to Search/Filter an inner ul li list view using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create some applications to use JavaScript to search for items in a list.
it can't show inner ul li (dropdown list)content......

The following is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/1e3swfr7/

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="show()">Click it Show hide peoples</a>
    <ul id="show_content">
      <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li> <!-- can't show it when I search "Billy" -->
      <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>   <!-- can't show it when I search "Bob" -->
    </ul>
  </li>      
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function search() { <!-- Search/Filter -->
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function show() {    <!-- hide/show drop down list -->
   var a = document.getElementById("show_content");
    if(a.style.display== "none"){
      a.style.display = "";  
    }else{
       a.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

It can't show **Billy** and **Bob** in drop-down list

any ideas how to show Billy and Bob in drop-down list???
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not get child elements of "myUL", because "Billy" and "Bob" are not directly child of "myUL". So try this kind of code

```
function search() { <!-- Search/Filter -->
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the parent of "Billy" and "Bob" does not get hidden.
I added class="alwaysshow" to the parent and made sure in the script that it does not get hidden.
Needs some more work to hide the parent if you do not search for its children but you should get the idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/bdLr4uma/

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li class="alwaysshow"><a href="#" onclick="show()">Click it Show hide peoples</a>
    <ul id="show_content">
      <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>      
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function search() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || li[i].className.indexOf("alwaysshow") > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```